# j2ee session migration and session replication

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat, cluster-computing

From the book `Head First Servlets and JSP, Second Edition` [P257](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/jsp/9780596516680/session-management-conversational-state/session_migration)

the author said:

> But there is only one HttpSession object for a given session ID per
>   web app, regardless of how many VM’s the app is distributed across.

however from tomcat documentation: [Clustering/Session Replication HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html)
it does say sessions can be replicated in multiple vms:

> The cluster is started and will establish a membership
>   (TomcatA,TomcatB). TomcatB will now request the session state from a
>   server that already exists in the cluster, in this case TomcatA.
>   TomcatA responds to the request, and before TomcatB starts listening
>   for HTTP requests, the state has been transferred from TomcatA to
>   TomcatB.

I don't know how to understand this.

Answer (score 3):

It's only the `HttpSession`'s state (basically, all of its serializable contents) which is been replicated to keep in sync among the servers in a cluster, not the object instance itself. Every individual server will still have only one instance of `HttpSession` object associated with the session ID per client-server session.

Comment: Each individual server has 1 instance of `HttpSession`? Or 1 cluster has only 1 `HttpSession` for a given session id?

Comment: A cluster does not have any Java objects. They live only in the JVM context which runs inside each app server. You should not confuse "instances of Java objects" with "the data it holds" (the state).